# Encrypt hard coded password in php script

Tags: php, encryption, passwords

How can I encrypt/hide my hard coded password in my PHP script to connect with the Active Directory over LDAP.

Here's my script:

```
$adminUsername = "administrator";
$adminPassword = "Admin123";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ON the LDAP create a new user/group with specific rights and use that account in your php script. You cannot hash/encrypt your password or LDAP would not accept it. Don't set your administrator passwords in a script on a server that is accessible to multiple persons.